# Are there cases of Democrats engaging in voter suppression?

Tags: united-states, election, voting, democratic-party

Modern Republicans are often accused of trying to [suppress the right to vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_suppression_in_the_United_States) for minorities.

Are there cases where the modern Democratic party (ie post Jim Crow) is accused of suppressing the right to vote for demographics that are less likely to vote for them? Do they use the same tactics as Republicans are accused of, or are they different?

Examples:

- closing of specific polling places not likely to vote for their party
- requiring specific IDs less likely to be owned by minorities
- purging voter registrations of specific demographics
- keeping voter registrations of specific demographics on hold
- misinforming specific demographics about voting location or time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84839/discussion-on-question-by-tim-are-there-cases-of-democrats-engaging-in-voter-sup).

Comment: Further comments deleted. If you want to debate the "defacto racist vs. deliberately racist" argument, please do so in the provided chatroom. Also, please try to stay civil while doing so.

Comment: What is your definition of suppression? Would enabling illegal votes be suppression since it cancels out an equivalent number of legal votes? Would attempting to disqualify military ballots be voter suppression? would 'finding' bags of ballots in car trunks and whatnot be voter suppression? Would standing outside polling places and intimidating voters be voter suppression? Would picking up absentee ballots from people in exchange for compensation that were filled in by those people (yeah right) be voter suppression?

Comment: Would doing everything in their power to ensure voting corruption can't be investigated be voter suppression? Would gerrymandering be voter suppression?

Comment: @Dunk No, Yes, No, Yes (but it would only be relevant to the question if organized by the Democratic party or at least by high-ranking Democrats), No, No, No. Some of the things that aren't voter suppression may or may not exist and could be considered election fraud, but imho aren't related to the question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no reported cases of Democrats suppressing votes in the same manner as Republicans are seen to be doing, however there are still some accusations of voter suppression that have been leveled at the party.

### Scheduling Off-Cycle Elections

Democrats have, in general, stood against attempts to bring local election schedules in line with one another. It is thought by some that this is because having these elections at unusual times leads to only the most motivated voters bothering to show up at the polls. Often, these are the workers directly affected by the election. For more information, take a look at [this article](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-democrats-suppress-the-vote/).

### Primary Elections

There have been accusations that Democrats deliberately make it difficult to switch your party affiliation to vote for an inspiring candidate in an attempt to ensure that mainstream, establishment candidates get the democratic nomination. For more information on the phenomenon, take a look [here](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/07/19/opinions/democrats-need-reform-new-york-primary-weaver/index.html).

In general, however, these cases seem more isolated than the Republican attempts, and to generally be isolated to elections with somewhat lower stakes. This is likely why they are less reported on, and not seen as such an intense issue.

Comment: +1 The first point is very interesting. I heard that Democrats are at a disadvantage in the midterms, and just assumed that that disadvantage scales further down (so they would actually not prefer off-cycle elections). But the linked analysis seems very reasonable. I'm not that much interested in primaries, as afaik parties could decide on their front-runner however they want (they could just throw a coin, or dictatorially determine the front-runner by party elders).

Comment: Your second point doesn't apply in my state, FWIW.  I suspect it varies state to state.  In Minnesota, you are restricted to voting one column only in the partisan part of the primary ballot, and you show up to whatever precinct caucus you like.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Not only are there reported cases, but there are documented cases of the Democratic Party suppressing voters in the same manner as Republican Party is now doing. See my example below on Louisiana voter suppression under the Democratic Party.

Comment: Is there anywhere that has a consolidated list of which states do the weird scheduling thing, and for which offices they do it?  AFAIK my state doesn't do anything like that directly, although running some types of elections in odd years can have some interesting effects.  ex in the aftermath of Trump's win the Pa Democrats were apparently more motivated to vote than normal in 2017 and elected the State Supreme Court judges who tossed the gerrymandered 2010 map for congressional districts.  I suspect the same circumstances resulted in them winning more lower judicial elections, but am unsure.

Comment: @Wes Regardless of whether ID laws are designed to suppress minority voting, this answer doesn't mention ID law, did you comment on the wrong answer?

Comment: @WesSayeed Did you mean to comment on the question rather than this answer?

Comment: @DavidThornley Yeah - I wasn't trying to claim this was a universal thing. I just knew it was the case in some places.

Comment: @birch I acknowledge there are historical examples, but I don't think they're especially applicable to the modern Democratic party, which is why I didn't mention this. Of course, you are entirely entitled to your opinion on the matter, and I respect your viewpoint.

Comment: @DanNeely I don't know of one. The article I linked refers to school board elections generally across a few states, and mentions elections for state office, fire commissioner and the school board all taking place off the federal cycle and at  different times to one another. Apparently "44 out of 50 [states] hold some state and local elections off the federal cycle" but I'm not sure of any specifics.

Comment: "Democrats have, in general, stood against attempts to bring local election schedules in line with one another." That's quite a generalization, considering that the linked article only discussed school board elections. Los Angeles recently moved its mayoral elections from odd-numbered years to midterm years, and [San Jose is considering moving from midterm years to presidential years](https://www.mercurynews.com/2018/10/02/san-jose-proposal-would-keep-sam-liccardo-as-mayor-two-more-years/). Both are major cities controlled by Democrats. It's easy to cherry pick when you focus on a narrow area.

Answer (score 34):

Note: this answers an earlier broader version of the Q. that was not limited to *modern* Democrats.

---

If historical answers are acceptable, then Democrats wrote the book on racist voter suppression.  Wikipedia's article [Disenfranchisement after the Reconstruction Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disenfranchisement_after_the_Reconstruction_Era) covers the Southern Democrat's foul tricks such as:

- [Poll taxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disenfranchisement_after_the_Reconstruction_Era#Poll_taxes).
- Literacy tests with [grandfather clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disenfranchisement_after_the_Reconstruction_Era#Grandfather_clause) so that whites who were illiterate could vote while blacks who were illiterate could not.
- [White primaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_primaries)
- [Requiring freedmen to prove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colfax_massacre#The_Louisiana_election_of_1872) they were over 21, while knowing that former slaves had no birth certificates.
- Impunity for murderous [white racist paramilitary violence and tyranny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colfax_massacre).

In those days it was the [Radical Republicans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_Republican) who fought against voter suppression.

The two parties virtually [traded places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_strategy) on racism in the mid-20th century, which can lead to brand confusion.  Sometimes modern racist Republicans exploit this brand confusion by calling themselves ["The Party of Lincoln"](https://www.history.com/news/how-the-party-of-lincoln-won-over-the-once-democratic-south) whilst advocating policies Lincoln would not have admired.

So there's a vile history of racist voter suppression on both sides.  Voter suppression is not *one* party's problem, it's everyone's (or at least everyone who's not trying to promote racism), and should properly be regarded as a general bipartisan reform issue.

---

Note:

In a comment, (since deleted by the moderator), commentator *T.E.D.* argued that modern political parties should bear no discredit for the wrongs done in their name by "wings" or factions that have since departed and joined other parties.  The argument seems similar to the merely feasible legalistic reasoning that the disingenuous descendants of a criminal made wealthy by terrible unpunished crimes are therefore free of any moral taint or responsibility to redress crimes they did not commit but enjoyed and inherited the rewards of, while the pauperized families of the deceased wealthy criminal's victims are considered solely responsible for their lot.

Comment: I thought about mentioning in my question that I'm not really interested in Jim Crow and related voter suppression, but decided against it because I thought it would be clear that I meant the modern Democratic party. On the other hand, I should probably have mentioned this, so thanks for your answer.

Comment: Though as you said, the parties basically traded places; this doesn't seem like a case of "voter suppression on both sides", but a continuation of the same suppression of the same minorities by the same (kind of) people, just under a different label. Voter suppression by "the other side" - ie Republicans - during that area would be interesting (but also not what the question is about)

Comment: I think an important distinction can be made between current and historical practices...

Comment: Lots of comments deleted. Please stay on-topic. The topic of this question is voter suppression, not party positions in general.

Answer (score 17):

If you're not making a distinction between vote suppression organized by the Democratic Party itself and vote suppression organized by its supporters, then you might find the Texas Attorney General's website interesting. The Texas AG has been aggressively prosecuting numerous cases of vote fraud, including at least one case involving what the AG's office describes as an ["organized vote fraud ring"](https://www.texasattorneygeneral.gov/news/releases/work-ag-paxtons-election-fraud-unit-results-arrests-4-members-organized-voter-fraud-ring-north-fort) operating in Fort Worth. According to the AG,

> Vote harvesting is accomplished generally in two phases: seeding and harvesting.  In the seeding phase, applications for mail ballot are proliferated in order to blanket targeted precincts with mail ballots.  Then, when ballots are mailed out by the election offices, harvesters attempt either to intercept the ballots outright, or to “assist” elderly voters in voting their ballots while ensuring that the votes are cast for the candidates of the harvesters’ choice. In most cases, the voters do not even know their votes have been stolen.

[An article in the Fort Worth Star-Telegram](https://www.star-telegram.com/news/local/community/fort-worth/article219920740.html) identifies the Democratic Party as the beneficiary of the scheme.

Comment: I would make that distinction, but if the supporters are linked closely enough to the Democratic party - eg not the NBPP as in another (deleted) answer - I think it would still make for a good answer. But I wouldn't consider voter fraud to be voter suppression, and I don't see that this case (if it existed as presented) is linked in any way to the Democratic party.

Comment: @tim Vote fraud is usually limited in its impact, but in this case they were systematically stealing, altering, or influencing ballots for targeted neighborhoods. Sounds like suppression to me.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. It seems that this is about 16 cases, but you are right that the vote of the affected people has been suppressed (if the case is indeed as laid out; I couldn't find any information apart from what you linked, and I'm a bit skeptical about the source; and there is of course still the question if/how this is linked to Democrats; hopefully we will know more in the future).

Comment: Seems debatable. If you look into actual caught and prosecuted cases of voter *fraud*, just about every one of them is done by fraudulently filling out absentee ballots. Further, its almost always in service of artificially pumping up the vote totals of a specific candidate, rather than an entire slate. This completely fits that pattern, so it really makes far more sense to consider it vote fraud like all those other cases. The FWST certainly reported it that way.

Comment: The Star-Telegram article actually **doesn't** appear to say that the Democratic Party were the beneficiaries. It does say that it was Democratic primaries that were affected, but that could be a plus or a minus to the party.

Comment: FYI - this is not voter suppression. We see dozens of charges, but there is only one allegation of a ballot being fraudulently submitted. All the other charges were related to requests for ballots or applications for ballots. It says in the cited newspaper article that they were "request ballots by mail for the Democratic Party for 2016 elections **for 13 people who had made no such requests.** If they made no requests for ballots, then the ballots being improperly intercepted did not prevent them from voting, and there is no indication that they were otherwise prevented from voting.

Comment: @T.E.D. - Actually, in this case the fraud is in the *request* for the ballots. They never got to the part where they submitted the ballots (with one exception).  However, that's more a credit to the AG for catching the crime in the early phases, though they do attempt to make it seem like more than it was. That's normal for any political office, though.

Answer (score 13):

TalkingPointsMemo is hosting several articles in a series about voter suppression. The series covers a lot of history about suppression and outright fraud, and most of the cases are at the hands of (surprise!) the GOP, targeting minority voters. But there is a notable exception in the series, which discusses Chicago around the middle of the 20th century (timeline isn't too clear) in which fraud, coercion, and suppression are used to favor Democrat candidates.

This is citing [Don Rose](https://keywiki.org/Don_Rose) as the source of the info, who was a leftist political activist beginning in the 40's, followed by many decades of civil rights activism and similar work.

> Cheating at elections had long been a Chicago tradition. According to Don Rose, a longtime liberal Chicago campaign consultant, the old paper ballots had offered all sorts of opportunities for trickery. But even after the city switched to voting machines there were ways to rig the system. If a voter tried to pull down one of the machine’s small levers, registering a Republican exception to a straight Democratic ticket, a strategically placed rubber band could bounce it back up again. The party bought votes with turkeys and nylon hosiery, and threatened public housing residents with eviction if they didn’t toe the line. Using laws designed to help people with disabilities, election judges “assisted” voters who were actually able-bodied. This required the presence of both a Republican and a Democratic election judge, but, Rose said, “you have to remember that in a tremendous number of precincts, usually in the black neighborhoods, the alleged Republican judges were really Democrats.” Judges could also simply call in the wrong totals. At least once, Rose said, that happened at gunpoint.
>
> The story about dead people voting in Chicago isn’t wrong, Rose said, but it was never the most common method, making up “10 or 15 percent of the total steal.”
>
> - Rick Perlstein And Livia Gershon | August 16, 2018

https://talkingpointsmemo.com/feature/stolen-elections-voting-dogs-and-other-fantastic-fables-from-the-gop-voter-fraud-mythology

Note: There is a bit longer version of the above in another article by one of the authors at https://washingtonspectator.org/gop-voting-fraud-election-2016/

Comment: I wouldn't describe the tactics used by Chicago (and other) Democrats as "suppression".  Quite the opposite: it extended the franchise even to those who were dead :-)  See "graveyard vote" for more info.

Comment: @jamesqf makes a really good point. While they are both definitely shenanigans, vote fraud and voter suppression are two very different things, and should not be confused. The question was asking about suppression, and this answer only provides examples of fraud.

Comment: @jamesqf, The rubber band in the voting machine canceling a Republican vote would be both vote suppression *and* vote fraud.

Comment: @T.E.D., Vote fraud is a felony, and we have constitutional amendments against vote suppression, describing those serious crimes with an endearing term like *"shenanigans"* draws a false equivalence implying those crimes are harmless misdemeanors.

Comment: @agc: I don't agree, just as a matter of definition.  I think suppression means preventing people from voting.  With the rubber band trick, they could vote all they want, but their votes weren't counted.

Comment: @jamesqf, Any *intentionally* uncounted vote is a suppressed vote.

Comment: @agc: I don't agree, but that's more a matter for the English Language & Usage site.

Answer (score 7):

The primary way that the Democratic party suppresses the vote is by clumping.  For example, in Massachusetts, there is roughly one Republican for every three Democrats by [voter registration](https://www.sec.state.ma.us/ele/eleenr/enridx.htm).  Yet there are no Republican members of Congress from Massachusetts.  If Republicans had as much representation as their share of the two-party registration, they would have two or three Representatives.  Even if Republicans only had as much share as their overall percentage of registrations, that would be still be at least one.  And of course, Democrats would be reduce from nine to three.  Because unaffiliated voters make up a majority of the voters in Massachusetts.

This also has an effect because it makes elections uncompetitive in Democratic areas.  Much has been made of California's huge lean towards Democrats.  But again, Republicans get about a third of the vote but only a quarter of the seats.  And in many elections, like Senate, governor, and president, California is completely noncompetitive.  So there is little incentive for Republicans to vote.  [Lopsided elections reduce turnout](https://www.sltrib.com/news/politics/2017/10/17/study-most-utah-races-are-noncompetitive-fueling-low-voter-turnout/).

It's true that these effects cut both ways.  In places where Republicans clump, it's Democrats whose vote is suppressed.  But the truth is that the most partisan areas are controlled by Democrats.  And with Democrats, there are usually Democrat enclaves within the Republican areas.  For example, Texas is a Republican state.  But Houston, Dallas, and Austin all have Democrat [mayors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mayors_of_the_50_largest_cities_in_the_United_States) and Representatives.  Fort Worth, San Antonio, and El Paso may not have Democratic mayors but still have Democratic Representatives.

Of the fourteen Representatives from New York City, only one is a Republican.  Republicans who live in other districts don't have the same opportunity to cast votes that count.

Both Democrats and Republicans benefit from the two-party system, but the Democrats benefit more.  The two-party system forces people to pick one side or the other.  We can again see this by looking at Massachusetts.  There, a majority of voters are unaffiliated.  They should have four or five Representatives but actually have none.  Democrats get all of the seats despite only making up a third of registrations.

Democrats also apportion and district seats by total population rather than voter eligible population.  So someone who lives in a district with many children and disenfranchised felons has a vote that counts more than those in older, less criminal districts.

One could say that these are demographic problems.  That's true.  But they remain addressable.  If we adopted proportionality, then seats would be distributed based on the number of people who vote.  We could get rid of the census, redistricting, and taxpayer financed primaries altogether.  There would just be one big election via proportional means (e.g. single transferable vote).  Candidates could continue to be limited to states, but apportionment would happen as part of the election.  That would incent all groups to participate.

Instead, Democrats came up with efficiency gap analysis, which suppresses third party votes, doesn't fix Massachusetts, California, and other partisan Democrat states, but does help Democrats in Republican states.

Proportional voting would make it easier for minorities and women to win as well.  Because they could clump together to vote for their candidates.  As is, Massachusetts is represented by seven white men and two white women.  Under proportionality, that might be more even by gender with two or three minority Representatives.

Clumping combines with partisan primaries to increase polarization also.  Because electability doesn't matter in a clumped district.  Even an obviously unqualified candidate can expect to win the general election after winning the correct primary.  And it's much easier to win a primary than a general election.  Because primaries only include a partisan group of voters, they tend to produce candidates who are ideologically in the middle of that subset rather than the population as a whole.  Meanwhile, if offered the choice, the voters excluded from the primary would prefer the more moderate candidate.

Comment: The first part is Gerrymandering, right? While AFAIK Republicans are much more [successfull](https://www.businessinsider.de/partisan-gerrymandering-has-benefited-republicans-more-than-democrats-2017-6?r=US&IR=T) in Gerrymandering, Democrats do indeed do it. But while unethical and not all that democratic, I wouldn't really consider this voter suppression. The two-party system also seems less than ideal, but is definitely not voter suppression.

Comment: Yes and no.  Wouldn't "clumping" be the only way possible for a Republican to get elected?  If the population were fairly homogeneously distributed and the boundary lines were drawn in a normal geometric way, the GOP would get outvoted 3 to 1 in each and every election for each and every district or seat.  Now, that's not the way populations actually distribute, but a 3 to 1 margin would suggest that no seats would/could be an expected outcome without any gerrymandering.

Comment: Clumping is not gerrymandering.  Clumping is where Democrats live in Massachusetts and Republicans live in Utah.  Gerrymandering can exacerbate clumping.  And the essential problem here is that liberals are happy to notice when the votes of their allies are suppressed but completely willing to ignore it when their opponents' votes are suppressed.  This is much like Republicans, who find worries about voter fraud (e.g. the 50,000 people whose voter registrations don't match other databases in Georgia) more important than expansive voter registration (the other databases may be wrong).

Comment: I think you're right that in states like Massachusetts the democratic party benefits far more from the 2 party system than the Republican party - *because the independent voters are voting for democrats*. Proportional voting would force people to actually affiliate with one of those parties: most likely with the one they most agree with. Trying to predict the outcome of a proportional vote without accounting for the re-registration that it would cause is quite misleading.

Comment: "Both Democrats and Republicans benefit from the two-party system, but the Democrats benefit more."  Not the case.  Dems have to win 7% more votes just to be a tossup in the House, and the Electoral college is nearly as bad.  Senate is actually worse.

Comment: By this argument wouldn't republicans be harmed on a national scale, if these systems were somehow made more fair in regards to population? HRC won the popular vote, after all.

Comment: @Adonalsium: How can you win something that does not exist?  And attempting to synthesize a "popular vote count" by adding together votes cast for electors doesn't provide meaningful information, because (1) the rules are different from state to state, and (2) winner-take-all significantly influences whether people bother to show up and vote.

Answer (score 5):

*"In 2009, The Department of Justice sued members of the New Black Panther Party for Self-Defense (a group unaffiliated with the Black Panther Party of the 1960s) for brandishing a "police-style baton" to intimidate voters outside a Philadelphia polling station during the 2008 presidential election"* (source: http://www.justice.gov/opa/pr/2009/January/09-crt-014.html)

I live in Fort Lauderdale, Florida and this type of voter intimidation continues to occur at my polling place.  During the 2016 election I had to navigate quite a gauntlet to submit my vote.  Although there was no evidence of batons or other weapons present,  the seemingly organized group appeared to apply intimidation tactics solely on racial rather than political party affiliation.

Comment: The NBPP is a hate group that is not aligned with the Democratic party, so this isn't really what I'm looking for.

Comment: @tim It's quite tenuous to assert that they aren't 'aligned' with the Democratic party. They aren't controlled by the Democratic party, but they certainly appeared to be supporting them.

Answer (score 4):

One specific case is Louisiana. [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_party_strength_in_Louisiana) shows that Democrats controlled all levels of government from roughly 1878 - 1980.

During that time, the state enforced many Jim Crow voter suppression tactics.

A specific example is the Lousiana Literacy Test from the 1960s. That test asked questions that were designed to give the white registrar assessing the test wide latitude in passing or failing anyone. It was used primarily to fail blacks trying to register to vote. More on that test [here](http://www.slate.com/blogs/the_vault/2013/06/28/voting_rights_and_the_supreme_court_the_impossible_literacy_test_louisiana.html).

Some example questions:

1. Draw a line around the number or letter of this sentence.
2. Draw a line under the last word in this line.
3. Cross out the longest word in this line.
4. Draw a triangle with a blackened circle that overlaps only its left corner.

Comment: Please see my [response](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/34671/are-there-cases-of-democrats-engaging-in-voter-suppression?noredirect=1#comment133263_34680) to a similar answer. These are really the same sort of people enacting laws for the same sorts of reasons, just under a different name. If you have examples from 1980, that would be different, but Jim Crow is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @tim If you're going to ignore evidence that the Democratic Party engages in the same behavior, why ask the question the way you did? You should ask, "Are there examples of anyone besides white males engaging in voter suppression," which would make your "same sort of people" comment explicit and would preempt the answers you're getting about parties rather than people.

Comment: I'm not. I upvoted the answer by @CoedRhyfelwr and plan to accept it in a day or two if no better answer comes along. I don't have specific statistics, but my guess would be that the Democratic party is also primarily white and male, so phrasing it like that wouldn't be what I'm looking for. In either case, "engages" seems like the wrong tense here, and while I could have been explicitly asking about the *modern* Democratic party, I think it was clearly implied. The number of comments and answer on this topic suggests that isn't the case though, so I updated my question.

Comment: @tim The parties are just not that different from each other.  The same sort of people are in both.

Comment: @tim I think your question is interesting because the answers highlight how voter suppression is a tool both parties are willing to use when they have "enough" control over states/federal government. However, because cycles of party control occur over decades (we've been in an R cycle for a while), people tend to forget the other party did it last time and map voter suppression onto something only 1 party does, when really it's something specific people do when they acquire concentrated power through the party apparatus.

Comment: @birch Well, Democrats controlled both chambers and the presidency for a while; I think they had a number of chances for further suppression since the 50s/60s which they didn't take (or couldn't take without changing their policy; suppressing the white male vote is probably more difficult than suppressing minority votes). My takeaway for now is that voter suppression is mostly a tool of white dominance (historically, by either party). That's not to say that either party doesn't use other tools than voter suppression to solidify gained power, but that's a broader topic.

Comment: @birch - That would be misleading, because people who aren't white men (in particular, some white *women*) have engaged in voter suppression on the basis of race, and in any case white men can, potentially engage in voter suppression for non-racist reasons. The "same sort of people" probably refers more to anti-black racists and their affiliates, who find a more comfortable home in the Republican Party these days.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I agree with you. I originally thought it would be white men only because they were the only ones elected to positions that set voting policy during Jim Crow, but even then lower-level officials and non-officials at all levels of society were suppressing voters, which likely includes many people who were not white men.